# Trying to use playwright with electron, but getting an error

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, loader, playwright

I'm using the react electron boilerplate and after installing playwright by using "npm install -D playwright" I'm getting 23 errors like these when trying to package it, development is fine. Thanks

```
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/playwright-core/bin/README.md 1:4
[0] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:4)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
[0] > See building instructions at [`//browser_patches/winldd/README.md`](../browser_patches/winldd/README.md)
[0] | 
[0] | 
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/bin/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./README.md
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/android/android.js 169:134-173
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/playwright.js 9:15-43
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/inProcessFactory.js 10:18-48
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/inprocess.js 3:24-53
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/index.js 18:0-43
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright/index.js 17:0-43
[0]  @ ./src/main/main.ts 21:19-40
[0] 
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/playwright-core/bin/android-driver-target.apk 1:2
[0] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:2)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
[0] (Source code omitted for this binary file)
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/bin/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./android-driver-target.apk
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/android/android.js 169:134-173
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/server/playwright.js 9:15-43
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/inProcessFactory.js 10:18-48
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/inprocess.js 3:24-53
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright-core/index.js 18:0-43
[0]  @ ./node_modules/playwright/index.js 17:0-43
[0]  @ ./src/main/main.ts 21:19-40

[0] webpack compiled with 23 errors
[0] npm run build:main exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually add to `./release/app/package.json`.

Example:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "playwright": "^1.17.2"
  },
```

From https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/docs/adding-dependencies/

> 1. If the module is native to a platform (like node-postgres), it should be listed under dependencies in ./release/app/package.json